# Trouble setting up home network ( isolating home server )

Tags: router, home-networking, dhcp, nat, home-server

So I have 2 routers, a switch, a few PCs and an old PC to become a home server. Right now, I have 1 of the routers connected to the switch which wires every computers. It's working fine.

This is my local network. I want to connect the server to the second router, which is going to be 'parent' of my local network. I am probably missing something here...Anyway, here's my full network configuration:

Network configuration:

[Network Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdLm4.png)

**LOCAL (PARENT) NETWORK**
**Router 1 (Linksys AC1900):**
 
IP = 192.168.1.1 --- Subnet mask: 255.255.255.192 --- NAT: ON --- DHCP: ON
**Home Server ( web server, game server, file sharing, etc.):**
IP = 192.168.1.2 --- Subnet mask: 255.255.255.192

**LOCAL NETWORK**
**Router 2 (Linksys WRT160Nv2):**
 
IP = 192.168.1.65 --- Subnet mask: 255.255.255.192 --- NAT: ON --- DHCP: ON

I had it working once, but the network was really slow so I restarted everything and then every ping gave critical errors. I was unable to connect to any router so I worked my way back to a stable single router network.

I had also set static routes so that the PCs from the local network could ping the server and vice-versa.

Comment: (1) As long as you’re editing the picture for us, why not use English words?  (2) The picture shows that “Réseau 1” is using the 0-63 range and “Réseau 2” is using 64-127 — but your text says that Router 1 is using the 64-127 range and Router 2 is using 0-63.   This is confusing.  (3) What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: (1,2) You're right, I'll edit the image to better fit my description. (3) Do you see anything wrong with my configuration? Is NAT and DHCP supposed to be enabled on both routers? Is using static paths between routers a good way to allow both subnets to communicate together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace either router with a switch, or disable routing on one, or simply eliminate one and put everything on one network with one DHCP server.

If you insist on setting up 2 routers and isolating your server for some reason, here are the instructions for your router:

http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=132275

[image]

Comment: Isn't more secure to isolate the server in a different network? And If I were to Isolate my server it would be considered a LAN/WAN configuration right? Thanks.

Comment: secure from what? You're in your house. You're wanting to route all traffic across both routers anyway. What security are you looking for? If you have guests, setup a secondary guest WiFi on your wireless router (most have the ability built-in) that can't talk to other computers on your network.

Comment: Oops, I totally forgot to mention that I want the server to be public (web server, game server, etc.). I want my local network to be 100% private and allow external connections to the server.

Comment: I'm making a lot of assumptions here. If you want to setup 2 routers in a LAN/WAN setup, you need to use 2 different IP subnets. I would use 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, but am I not using 2 different subnets with my current configuration?

Comment: No. You'd need to use 192.168.1.65-127 for one and 192.168.1.129-191 for the other if you use that subnet mask. Using 255.255.255.0 for your subnet mask is just easier/clearer.

Comment: Hmmm...Okay, maybe that's what I was missing, I'll try that out! Thanks again!